# Redux presentational properties similar to decorator pattern

Tags: reactjs, redux, decorator

Say the state of our application container is so (straight from the server):

```
[
  {first: 'tyrion', last: 'lannister', email: 'tmoney@lannister.com'},
  {first: 'jaime', last: 'lannister', email: 'jaime@lannister.com'}
]
```

We hand our data down to the presentational component, but the designers have asked for a capitalized full name, and obfuscated email.

So we want to render something like:

```
<div>
   <p>Tyrion Lanniser - tmoney@***.com</p>
   <p>Jaime Lanniser - jaime@***.com</p>
</div>
```

How **should** we handle purely presentational transformations of the data in the react/redux world?

Coming from the Rails world, I would add a decorator function in the presentation component like below so that it's the presentation component's responsibility to add properties that are rendered... not the reducer or container component:

```
const decorate = (person)=> {
  return {
    ...person,
    _full_name: capitalize(person.first_name + ' ' + person.last_name),
    _email: obfuscate(person.email)
  }
}

# ...
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  state = {
    persons: this.props.persons.map((person)=> decorate(person))
  }
}
```

But this seems to be an anti-pattern? Why? What are the downsides of this approach? This **feels** clean to me as the underlying data/state isn't changed, the child component, simply adds presentational properties to the data it receives.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about your question.. when you retrieve the data via ajax, you're saving it in the redux store right? then connecting your presentational component to your store?

Comment: Furthermore, the sentence: "render the data.. in the reducer / container" doesn't make any sense. at the end of the day, it's always some presentational component that's going to render stuff

Comment: Yeah, this question assumes that everything is 'hooked' up and RAW server data is in the redux store. I'm just trying to get specifics on presentational properties (capitalization, obfuscation, formatting, etc.)

Comment: Is there something else I can say to answer your question more specifically?

Comment: sorry, was busy. Will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referring to as an anti-pattern. This line is confusing:

```
this.state.persons = this.opts.persons.map((person)=> decorate(person))
```

because you don't need `this.state` if you're storing stuff in the redux store.
In any case, transformations make a lot of sense in the `mapStateToProps` function of `react-redux`.

```
connect(state => ({ persons: state.persons.map(decorate) }))
(
  props => 
    <div>
      {/* do something with props.persons in presentation */}
    </div>
)
```

That's a completely logical thing to do, in fact it's so common that there's a library that memoizes state transforms for this exact purpose in combination with redux: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Comment: Ah. that makes sense. My question is probably funky for you because we're using a bastardized Riot.js toolchain that mimics react.... and NOT using `mapStateToProps`.... but we probably should.

Comment: oh.. ok well I just saw your edit and taking in state from somewhere else and transforming it into local state IS an antipattern because you create two sources of truth. transforms should never become new state.. just transform it and return the presentation right away